# Calculate the SUMIFS on Calculated Column in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to replicate a excel formulae in a new measure in Power BI. Unfortunately, since SUMIFS are not present by default, we have to write the formulae, the issue with writing this is, all the examples shown as ways to write SUMIFS. We have to hardcode the options into the query. Which I don't want to.

I am looking for an option like in Excel in which it automatically identify the item in the column and calculate the SUMIF accordingly.
Please note that `Weightage Selection` is created by using `New Measure`.

This is the code which I wrote for this

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1 [Weightage Selection]),ALLEXCEPT('Sheet1',Sheet1[Location]))
```

But I am getting the error:

`Column 'Weightage Selection' in table 'Sheet1' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.`

[image]

Attached is the image of the formulae created in Excel.

[image]

As I explained in the image there is only 2 unique items but in the file I am planning on creating there will be a lot more. Which is why I want it to dynamically pick up the row items and calculate SUMIFS accordingly.

Attached is the data set,

[image]

Apologies in advance if I am have missed something which is required as a part of question. This is the first question, I am asking for Power BI so I am not entirely clear.

Please let me know if you want additional info, I will gladly share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

[image]

```
New = CALCULATE(SUMX(Sheet1, [Weightage Selection]), ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1, Sheet1[Location]))
```

Comment: Slight change, the column here is a created measure, the `Weightage Selection`  column here is a created measure. How would that change the formulae, I noticed that when I write the statement, it does not pick up the column names because of that.

Comment: I wrote this code `Measure = CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1 [Weightage Selection]),ALLEXCEPT('Sheet1',Sheet1[Location]))` and it is not working. Can you tell me what is it, that I did wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been racking my brain forever with this. Cant get it right for some reason.

Comment: As a measure, this works perfectly for me. Measure = CALCULATE(SUM('Sheet1'[Weightage Selection]), ALLEXCEPT('sheet1', 'Sheet1'[Location]))

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: I have updated it in the Question. Let me add an image as well.

Comment: Try removing the space between the table and column name

Comment: I have done that. When I do that, it does not show any of the created Measures. It only shows the Columns which were uploaded from the Excel file. It like it isnt even showing the New Measures I created in the formuale. It also shows `Parameter is not the correct type` with a read line under the syntax `'Sheet1'[Weightage Selection]`.

Comment: You will have to share the .pbix as the code is correct and working on my sample.

Comment: How do I share that?

Comment: I have made the pbix file but I can upload the file in Chat. What to do?

Comment: Add it to a share somewhere online and share a link

Comment: Attached is the Google Drive Link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Az66rdBG2noGfLgdNqYwKlWY6RKvrzm7/view?usp=drive_link or I have sent you connection request on LinkedIn and I can share the file once you connect.

Comment: the file is shared. Please have a look.

Comment: I'll update now.

Comment: I didn't realize that you have made the update. I checked it and it worked. What was the difference? Did you realize the issue which we were facing?

Comment: It is sometimes hard to communicate on SO without seeing your actual setup. Once you provided the .pbix, the problem became clear and the solution was simple.

Comment: Do you know why it was not recongising any measures? Was that an issue of using `SUM` instead of `SUMX`

Comment: Yes, you need SUMX for that.

Comment: OK Thanks. The problem is that I ran into another issue where I am trying to divide a value of a column with the sum of the entire value of the column. And while doing that I am running into the same error. This is the code `Agg Forecast Accuuracy = IFERROR(([Forecast Accuracy]/SUM([Weightage Selection])*[Forecast Accuracy]),0)` and this `The SUM function only accepts a column reference as an argument.` How do I resolve this? I would like to learn what I am missing in this situation.

Comment: You'd best ask a new question with all the relevant info as comments are difficult for this. The difference is that SUMX is an iterator whilst SUM is not.